# PHP Session Not Saving Upon Refresh

Tags: php, mysql, session

So, I have a PHP class that has a method which updates a session variable called `$_SESSION['location']`. But the problem is, each time the method is called, it doesn't find the saved session variable, and tells me it isn't set. It's supposed to store a location ID, and the method pulls the next location from a MySQL database based on the session variable, then storing the new ID. But the place in the SQL code, that's supposed to include the variable, is empty.

I do have `session_start()` at the beginning of the page. I've tried manually setting the variable, and it doesn't do anything either. Also tried to reach that variable from another PHP page, and no luck either. Please help.

Small sample of my code:

```
class location {
@session_start();
function compass($dir) {
    $select  = $_SESSION['location'];

    if($dir == "north") {
        $currentlat = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `lat` FROM `locationdb` WHERE id=".$select), 0, "lat");
        $currentlon = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `lon` FROM `locationdb` WHERE id=".$select), 0, "lon");
        $sql = "[THE SQL CODE THAT GETS THE NEXT LOCATION]";
        $id = mysql_result(mysql_query($sql), 0, "id");

        $_SESSION['location'] = $id;

        $return['loc']        = $this->display_location($id);
        $return['lat']        = $this->display_lat($id);
        $return['long']       = $this->display_long($id);
        $return['id']      = $id;
    }

    return $return;
}
}
```

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: You should put `session_start();` at the top of the page outside of the class. It should just be included on the pages at load. Where do you set the `$_SESSION['location']`?

Comment: This is one example why error suppression (@) should rarely be used and only for very specific purposes.

Comment: @Devon has a good point. You should remove the `@` and enable error display (if not already) using `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to see what's happening. And that'll probably save 80% of your trips to SO ;)

Comment: Ok, I removed the error suppression and enabled the error display. I also moved `session_start()` to the very first line of the file, but no luck.

Comment: look for flow/logical errors in your code, e.g., whether the session variable is being set in first place (that code block runs?).

Comment: Is it required to initialize a session variable in PHP?

Comment: How do you set the `$_SESSION['location']` if not already set? That's the problem with your whole method. It's dependent on that session variable being set in the first place, so where is that first set? If it's being set on this method, it's definitely flawed because `$select` is empty all the time if `$_SESSION['location']`  not set outside of this method somewhere.

Comment: If it isn't set already, then wouldn't doing `$_SESSION['location']` set it?

Comment: Do you get this problem in other browsers? Maybe you've disabled cookies in your test browser, the PHP Session depends on a cookie in your browser.

Comment: It's been tested in multiple browsers on multiple computers running different platforms.

Comment: It appears that on the first load, the _SESSION['location'] is not set (is empty) so when you query for lat & long, nothing matches, so you don't get the $id you want in the query you didn't post, and then when you try to set the _SESSION['location'] with that $id, nothing is set. Repeat on the next load.  You need some sort of default if _SESSION['location'] is not set initially.

Comment: If I sign in with my account on the site, it takes me to my default location. And I did have a piece of code that randomizes the location if it isn't set, but I didn't think that was relevant to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code

**Dont use session_start() in this file.

For simple testing first add this inside your compass() function.

```
 $_SESSION['location'] .= 'World';
```

Then create a php script with these codes.

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['location'] = 'Hello';
   include_once('*your name of class file*');
   $obj = new location(); 
   $obj -> compass('north');
   echo $_SESSION['location'];
?>
```

Run this script

If the output is "HelloWorld" then your $_SESSION['location'] is working.

Answer (score 0):

Check your phpinfo(), to see if the session save path is defined. If not, define a directory to store the sessions. In your code:

session_save_path('/DIRECTORY IN YOUR SERVER');

Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

This is closer to what your method should look like. There are some settings that will help reduce errors being thrown when running the function. With this function, and other suggestions, you should be able to remove the error your are getting.

```
class location
    {
        public  function compass($dir = '')
            {
                // Set the $select by $_SESSION or by your function
                $select =   (isset($_SESSION['location']))? $_SESSION['location']: $this->myFunctionToSetDefault();

                // I set $dir to empty so not to throw error
                if($dir == "north") {
                        $currentlat =   mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `lat` FROM `locationdb` WHERE id=".$select), 0, "lat");
                        $currentlon =   mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `lon` FROM `locationdb` WHERE id=".$select), 0, "lon");
                        $sql        =   "[THE SQL CODE THAT GETS THE NEXT LOCATION]";
                        $id         =   mysql_result(mysql_query($sql), 0, "id");

                        $_SESSION['location']   =   $id;
                        $return['loc']          =   $this->display_location($id);
                        $return['lat']          =   $this->display_lat($id);
                        $return['long']         =   $this->display_long($id);
                        $return['id']           =   $id;
                    }

                // This will return empty otherwise may throw error if $return is not set
                return (isset($return))? $return:'';
            }
    }
```